# Sprite Kit Swift - Character accelerate and decelerate

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skaction

I'm new to Swift Sprite Kit, I wanted to move a node with start speed = 0, until maximum speed when a button is press and hold for 2 seconds and decelerate with -5 speed until minimum speed when the button released. I've done something like this:

```
func moving(force : CGFloat){

    self.player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:force*cos(player.zRotation + 1.57079633), dy: initialforce*sin(player.zRotation + 1.57079633)))
}
```

In touch function:

```
let timerAction = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.05)

     let update = SKAction.run({
          if(self.initialforce < Constants.maximumMoveForce){
               self.force += 1.0
             }else{

                    self.moving(force: Constants.maximumMoveForce)

                    self.force = Constants.maximumMoveForce

                }
            })
      let sequence = SKAction.sequence([timerAction, update])
      let repeats = SKAction.repeatForever(sequence)
      self.run(repeats, withKey:"repeatAction")
```

and how am I gonna decelerate it at touchEnd? Or am I making wrong approach? Need help.

Comment: Try not to mix actions with physics unless you absolutely have to.  To decelerate,  you can change how friction/linearDamping behaves based on velocity speed

Comment: Hi, I'm very new to SpriteKit world. How am i gonna move the player for specific direction it is facing. For example, i can make the player rotate, however, i want the player to move forward(accelerate) at the angle it is facing when a button is pressed. This must be a mixture of physicbody and skaction, right? Can you guide me a little, i'm somewhere stucked.

Comment: your code already has it facing the way he is looking,  now if you are allowing steering while accelerating,  you do what you did to the impulse and apply it to velocity instead.  Basically, calculate distance of velocity `sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)` and multiply it by the cos and sin of your angle

Comment: Hi, I don't really get you, do you means I have to make my func moving(initialforce : CGFloat) { self.player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: initialforce*cos(player.zRotation + 1.57079633), dy: initialforce*sin(player.zRotation + 1.57079633))} instead?